# Problem with the import of packets in antlrworks

Tags: java, import, package, javac, antlrworks

Have to create a package defined by me, containing some of the classes, and I recall that package in a file .java created of the program AntlrWorks in which i did the import. Package named "com.project.redfox" . I compiled the code with the command: "javac Test.java provaParser.java provaLexer.java" but I get the error that not exist the package.

In the grammar have added :

```
grammar prova;

@hader{
      import com.project.redfox;
}
....something......
```

I created the package "com.project.redfox" within of the project redfox developed in NetBeans, therefore the directory com/project/redfox is in the directory redfox.

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post the full error message or your Antlr Grammar (if you're allowed to).

Comment: @ Matt von Rohr:"package com.wikirates does not exist import com.wikirates.core;"

Comment: @Tanuzzo88, `com.wikirates` is not in your classpath. The compiler cannot find them. Are you really only doing `javac Test.java parser.java lexer.java`? Is the ANTLR jar in your classpath? Can you post your grammar and the `Test.java` class?

Comment: @Bart Kiers: before of compile, run : export CLASSPATH= .../antlr-3.3/lib/antlr-3.3-complete.jar, then run : "java org.antlr.Tool prova.g", and than run : "javac Test.java parser.java lexer.java".

Comment: No, that would then be `javac Test.java provaParser.java provaLexer.java`. But like I said before: your compiler can't find `com.wikirates` which you are probably using in some class in your `com.project.redfox` package.

Comment: I was wrong to write the first, indeed i ran javac Test.java provaParser.java provaLexer.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formally answer your question: `javac` can't find the package `com.wikirates` which you are probably using in `com.project.redfox`.

Note that I assumed `redfox` is a class. If it's a package, you need to import all classes from it like this: `import com.project.redfox.*;` instead of `import com.project.redfox;` (assuming that there *are* classes in `com.project.redfox`...).